Integration with polar coordinates in high dimensions and function space $(H^{1}\cap L^{\infty})(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ (academic paper)
This is from the next following paper.
Let $u$ classical solutions, i.e, $u\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ and nonconstant radial solution of
$$
-\Delta u=f(u) \quad \text{in} \quad \mathbb{R}^{N}
$$
where $f\in C^{1}(\mathbb{R})$.
Lemma
Let $N \geq 2$ and $u$ be a nonconstant radial stable solution of (1.1). Then, there exists $K > 0$ such that
$$
\int_r^{\infty} \frac{ds}{s^{N-1} u_r(s)^2} \leq K r^{-2\sqrt{N-1}}, \quad \forall r \geq 1.
$$
Proof :
$u_r$ is the usual radial derivative of $u$, does not vanish in $(0, \infty)$. This is implicitly said in the above inequality.
it begins by using Lemma 2.2 of the paper : On the stability of radial solutions of semilinear
elliptic equations in all of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$
$$
(N-1) \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{u_r(|x|)^2 \eta(x)^2}{|x|^2} \, dx \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} u_r(|x|)^2 |\nabla \eta(x)|^2 \, dx,
$$
for every $\eta \in (H^1 \cap L^\infty)(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with compact support in $\mathbb{R}^N$.
Applying this inequality to a radial function $\eta(|x|)$, we obtain:
$$
(N-1) \int_0^{\infty} u_r(t)^2 \eta(t)^2 t^{N-3} \, dt \leq \int_0^{\infty} u_r(t)^2 \eta'(t)^2 t^{N-1} \, dt.
$$

doubt
I'm not sure how you can go from the first inequality with integrals to the second inequality with integrals. I think it is using an integration with porlar coordinates in high-dimensional like
\begin{equation}
  \int_{\Omega} f(x) dx=N w_{N}\int_{0}^{R}\tilde{f}(|x|) r^{N-1} dr
 \end{equation}
where $ω_{N}$ is the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{N}$. 
By passing to the limit as R → ∞, if f is a continuous and improperly Riemann integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ which is radial, then
\begin{equation}
  \int_{\Omega} f(x) dx=N w_{N}\int_{0}^{}\tilde{f}(|x|) r^{N-1} dr
 \end{equation}
This expression comes from here But if you want to use it, the function $\eta$ has to be continuous and improperly Riemann integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$.
How to prove it if you know that $\eta\in (H^{1}\cap L^{\infty})(\mathbb{R}^{N})$? 
My argument is that if you know that the function $\eta\in L^{\infty}$ then is bounded by definiton of the space $L^{\infty}$ and thus Riemman integral function, but you need improperly Riemman integrable also, I'm not sure that if i can claim it.
